# jQuery ui tabs don't rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've added jquery-ui tabs on my page

```
    var verticalTabs = $("#tabs-vertical");

    verticalTabs.tabs({
        fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: '2000' },
        show: function (event, ui) {
            var shownTab = $("#someId");

            if (false == shownTab.hasClass("someClass")) {
                shownTab.addClass("someClass");
            }
        }
    }).tabs("rotate", 5000, true).show();
```

When tab is shown, I've added some css class describing background image to the panel, in order to provide some sort of lazy-loading. This works only when firebug console is opened in FF. Other browsers show me the same behavior. When I'm click on tab it shows me the background of my 'div' element as I expect but it doesn't rotate my tabs.

UPD. debugging shows that my handler is invoking after each 5 seconds but browser doesn't want to re-render applied changes.

Any ideas why it doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The hasClass and addClass methods are expecting the class along without the period.

```
var verticalTabs = $("#tabs-vertical");

verticalTabs.tabs({
    fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: '2000' },
    show: function (event, ui) {
        var shownTab = $("#someId");

        if (false == shownTab.hasClass("someClass")) {
            shownTab.addClass("someClass");
        }
    }
}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true).show();
```

I wonder if that will help.